# Adding an external library to proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I'm adding proguard to my project, but get an exception when I try to build an apk with minifyEnabled set to true. The exception I get is about an external library I have which im not able to add to proguard rules file.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You should be able to exclude any class from ProGuard: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code

Comment: @KenWolf i've tried excluding the library classes with the -keep option but it's not working